# ASP.NET MVC Core: How can I access a model's property by index?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Let's say I have the following class in my Model:

```
public class Person
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    public string Surname{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a table in my View where headers 'First Name' and 'Surname' are created automatically using something like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!-- 1a (fake code) -->
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(n => n.getProperty(1))</th> 

            <!-- 1b (fake code) -->
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(n => n.getProperty(2))</th>

            <!-- 2a -->
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(n => n.FirstName)</th> 

            <!-- 2b -->
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(n => n.Surname)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

where 1a and 2a should be functionally equivalent. Same with 2a and 2b.

Is there any way to get this done?

Comment: As far as I know there is no such thing as an index of properties of a class, the order is not strict and is otherwise irrelevant.  With the DisplayNameFor Html helper you especially wont be able to do what you are asking.

Comment: You could always create a `HtmlHelper` extension method (say `@Html.TableHeadersFor(m => m)`) to generate the `<thead>` element and its child's, but its unclear what your issue is with using `@Html.DisplayNameFor(n => n.FirstName)`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom attribute (e.g. IndexAttribute), and then decorate the Person properties with it:

```
public class Person
{
    [Index (Value = 0)]
    public long ID {get; set; }

    [Index (Value = 1)]
    [Display (Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName {get; set; }

    [Index (Value = 2)]
    [Display (Name = "Surname")]
    public string Surname {get; set; }
}
```

Then create an HtmlHelper, which through reflection do `n.GetProperty(n);`

Comment: This easily can cause bugs, as your example shows, (having two 0 index's).  You can do this based on the declaration order using reflection as well

Comment: Thanks Johnny! I fixed the duplicate index.

Comment: Seriously? And where is the code showing the OP how to do that!

Comment: Stephen Muecke, thanks for your comment!

I focused on the problem and approach that I would use if this problem happened to me.

IMHO, implementing a custom attribute and an html helper, although they can make the answer richer, are not part of the scope of the question.